# Using $elemMatch in native mongodb with node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm working with mongodb native driver in node js(Modulus server). I have document structure like sub documents array within main documents. Structure is like bellow,

```
{ "adname" : "First Advertisement Image", "adsize" : "600*58", "adstatus" : "on", "modifiedAt" : "31-01-2014 05:22:26 PM", "created" : "31-01-2014 03:29:20 PM", "_id" : { "$oid" : "52eb73f8584fbf0000000001" }, "advertisements" : [{ "advname" : "diamond and jewellery", "advexpiredate" : "10-02-2014", "advduration" : "10000", "advstatus" : "on", "advshortimage" : "1391420178839-advertisement-download.jpg", "advlongimage" : "1391420179094-advertisement-bangleimages.jpg", "advid" : 1391420179600, "createdAt" : "03-02-2014 03:06:19 PM" },{ "advname" : "xyz jewellery", "advexpiredate" : "10-02-2014", "advduration" : "10000", "advstatus" : "on", "advshortimage" : "1391420178839-advertisement-download.jpg", "advlongimage" : "1391420179094-advertisement-bangleimages.jpg", "advid" : 1391420199800, "createdAt" : "03-02-2014 03:06:19 PM" } ] }
{ "adname" : "Second Advertisement", "adsize" : "260*58", "adstatus" : "on", "modifiedAt" : null, "created" : "31-01-2014 05:23:36 PM", "_id" : { "$oid" : "52eb8ec033d3510000000001" }, "advertisements" : [] }
{ "adname" : "Third Advertisement", "adsize" : "156*58", "adstatus" : "on", "modifiedAt" : null, "created" : "31-01-2014 05:24:18 PM", "_id" : { "$oid" : "52eb8eea33d3510000000002" }, "advertisements" : [] }
{ "adname" : "Fourth Advertisement", "adsize" : "250*290", "adstatus" : "on", "modifiedAt" : null, "created" : "31-01-2014 05:24:48 PM", "_id" : { "$oid" : "52eb8f0833d3510000000003" }, "advertisements" : [] }
```

and i have to retrieve particular sub document from any one main document based on both document id.I have used the following code in node js but i couldn't retrieve as i'm expecting.

```
exports.getAddsByAdvertisementId = function(id,adid,callback)
{
    advertisement.find({ _id: getObjectId(id) }, { advertisements: { $elemMatch: { advid: adid } } }, function(e,adds) {
        if(e) callback(e,null);
        else {
            adds.toArray(function(error, results) {
                if(error) callback(error,null);
                else callback(null,results);
            });
        }   
    });
}
```

For example if i pass _id:52eb73f8584fbf0000000001 and  advertisements.advid:1391420179600 means (ie. getAddsByAdvertisementId(52eb73f8584fbf0000000001,1391420179600)
my result should be

```
{ "advname" : "diamond and jewellery", "advexpiredate" : "10-02-2014", "advduration" : "10000", "advstatus" : "on", "advshortimage" : "1391420178839-advertisement-download.jpg", "advlongimage" : "1391420179094-advertisement-bangleimages.jpg", "advid" : 1391420179600, "createdAt" : "03-02-2014 03:06:19 PM" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably what you mean by not getting what you are expecting is that you do not get a document returned.

Check that the value you are passing in as `adid` is not a string, or cast it to an int inside your function.

Also since you are looking up documents with the primary `_id` first, you are only ever going to get 1 result or nothing. Use [findOne](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) instead to avoid going into an array that will only have 1 item.